# How to redirect undefined RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what I've currently written in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact contact.php 
RewriteRule ^browse browse.php 
RewriteRule ^contact/ contact.php 
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy-policy.php
RewriteRule ^signup register.php
RewriteRule ^register register.php
```

So when a user requests http://mydomain.com/welcome, which is not defined in the `.htaccess` file, it will result in a "404 Not Found" page.

Instead, I'd like to redirect pages that aren't explicitly defined in the `.htaccess` to another script, and pass the original URL. I don't want to use `ErrorDocument`s here. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ErrorDocument`s?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^contact contact.php 
RewriteRule ^browse browse.php 
# why is contact the only one with a slash at the end?
RewriteRule ^contact/ contact.php 
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy-policy.php
RewriteRule ^signup register.php
RewriteRule ^register register.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /other.php [L]
```

Comment: After addin that,d whole site stop working and this was the error-> Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.